# Директива return

Tags: javascript

- Встретил скрипт, который я не понял.
- Как переменная **woman** может использовать свойство **husband**,
  если его нет в объекте.
- Вдобавок к этому, что здесь делает **return**?
- Он перезаписывает свойства объектов, которых нет?

```js
function marry(man, woman) {
  woman.husband = man;
  man.wife = woman;

  return {
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  }
}

let family = marry({
  name: "John"
}, {
  name: "Ann"
});
```

Comment: если свойства не было, то оно будет добавлено. а return возвращает новый объект с указанными свойствами

Comment: Получается return добавляет еще два новых свойства в объект?

Comment: какие еще два два? оператор просто возвращает объект состоящий из двух свойств. нет там "еще два", а просто два.

Comment: husband, wife, father, mother это же 4 свойства?

Comment: у вас тут в итоге 3 объекта `woman { husbnad....}`, `man: { wife ...}` и `family ; { monther: .., father ...}`. с чего вдруг вы думаете что оно как то смешивается. У вас просто определяется объект `{ father, mother}` и он же возвращается. это новый объект.  что-то вы зациклились не на том.

Comment: Получается 3 объекта и 4 свойства?